# can't fetch api data and store with vuex - vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have problem about api fetch with vuex. And there is no problem with my endpoint. I can see the json data. But when I try to fetch it i can't store the data and displaying console error below.

> Error in mounted hook: "TypeError:
>   _api_article_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default.getArticles is not a function"

About my import and export:

**App.js**

```
window._ = require('lodash');

try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('foundation-sites');
} catch (e) {}

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}

import Vue from 'vue';
import router from './routes.js';
import store from './store.js';

new Vue({
     router,
     store,
}).$mount('#app')
```

**config.js**

```
var api_url = 'mywebsite.com/api';

export const ESTATE_CONFIG = {
    API_URL: api_url,
}
```

**api/article.js**

```
import { ESTATE_CONFIG } from '../config.js';

export default {
    getarticles: function(){
        return axios.get( ESTATE_CONFIG.API_URL + '/articles' );
    },
}
```

**Store.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

import { articles } from './modules/articles.js'

export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        articles,
    }
});
```

**modules/articles.js**

```
import ArticleAPI from '../api/article.js';

export const articles = {
    state: {
        articles: [],
        articlesLoadStatus: 0,

        article: {},
        articleLoadStatus: 0
    },
    getters: {
        getArticlesLoadStatus( state ){
            return state.articlesLoadStatus;
        },
        getArticles( state ){
            return state.articles;
        },
    },
    mutations: {
        setArticlesLoadStatus( state, status ){
            state.articlesLoadStatus = status;
        },
        setArticles( state, articles ){
            state.articles = articles;
        },
    },
    actions: {
        loadArticles( { commit } ){
            commit( 'setArticlesLoadStatus', 1 );

            ArticleAPI.getArticles()
                .then( function( response ){
                  commit( 'setArticles', response.data );
                  commit( 'setArticlesLoadStatus', 2 );
                })
                .catch( function(){
                  commit( 'setArticles', [] );
                  commit( 'setArticlesLoadStatus', 3 );
                });
        },
    },
}
```

I need help about this. Because I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.  And of course there is no problem with the endpoint. I can see the json data. But my `vuex` store is empty. And I have an error above.

Comment: It looks like a capitalization issue.  The API's function is not capitalized so it should be `ArticleAPI.getarticles`

Comment: you solved it. thank you for the tip. Also if you push this as answer I will check it. @Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates that an exported function called `getArticles` does not exist in *api/article.js*.

Taking a look at that module, it looks like a capitalization issue. The function is not capitalized so when calling it, use:

```
ArticleAPI.getarticles
```